# how do you keep meteor from clearing form on update

Tags: angularjs, meteor

I have a meteor / angular app with my index.ng.html page looking like

```
<div>
    {{1+4}}
    <form id = "myForm" name="myForm" >
        <input type="text" name = "username"/>
        <input type="text" name = "password"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

When I update the file by changing 1+4 to 1+6, any pre-filled information I have in my form is lost when the page "reloads".

How can I keep from loosing data when the page reloads?

Comment: Try using event.preventDefault();

Answer (score 1):

Store the data in a `Session` object. This should survive a hot code reload but *not* a manual page refresh.

```
Template.xxx.events({
    'change input': function(e,tmpl) {
        var fieldName = tmpl.$(e.currentTarget).attr("name");

        Session.set('field' + fieldName, e.currentTarget.value);
    }
});

Template.xxx.helpers({
    valueForField = function(fieldName) {
        return Session.get("field" + fieldName);
    }
});
```

Then you can use this in your html:

```
<form id = "myForm" name="myForm" >
        <input type="text" value="{{valueForField 'username'}}" name = "username"/>
        <input type="text" value="{{valueForField 'password'}}" name = "password"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
```

It's obviously a bit tedious. Meteor used to do this natively using a 'preserve-inputs' package, but it looks to be [deprecated](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/preserve-inputs).

Comment: I'll upvote this but it's not the solution I was looking for... The fact I have to create template events and helpers defeats the simplicity of meteor.